# how to choose the source points and destination points in homography matrix calculation programmatically

Tags: python, opencv, homography

I want to calculate the birds eye view for the given scene. So I want calculate the corresponding points that is source and destination points for calculating homography matrix programmatically . I don't know how to choose those points:

```
pts = np.array([
    (abs(2*width/8),abs(height)),
    (abs(10*width/8),abs(height)),
    (abs(5*width/8),abs(4*height/8)),
    (abs(2*width/8),abs(4*height/8))
])
dst = np.array([
    [0, height],
    [width, height],
    [width, 0],
    [0, 0]], dtype = "float32")

h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts, dst)
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, h, (320,240))
```

in above code I am fixing the source and destination points. How to calculate those points programmatically from frames.

Comment: You may need to detect Points of interest in the given frame, There are a lot of techniques to do the same, like template matching, color segmentation, etc.

Comment: cv2.findHomography(pts, dst) in this method i need source and corresponding destination points for birds eye view .so i am asking to how to calculate those points automatically

Comment: My answer would be same again]